# TSNode, JSDOM y pkg npm - Error! setter must have exactly one formal parameter

Tags: npm, pkg

de antemano muchísimas gracias, quisiera solucionar el siguiente problema que tengo al querer empaquetar mi API con pkg, este mismo lo instale a través de npm por consola.

Bueno el problema es que no me permite poder hacer el empaquetado del archivo ejecutable al momento de correr el comando por consola, me tira el siguiente error:

```
PS C:\Users\....\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\....> pkg . --out-dir C:\Users\....\OneDrive\Escritorio\CarpetaDestino
> pkg@4.4.9
> Targets not specified. Assuming:
  node12-linux-x64, node12-macos-x64, node12-win-x64
> Error! setter must have exactly one formal parameter (446:2)
  C:\Users\....\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\....\node_modules\jq\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\level2\html.js
```

Al entrar en el documento que me señala arriba, y revisar la línea que marca encontre esto:

```
 set head() { /* noop */ },
```

Revise versiones anteriores y no encuentro movimientos en esa línea (de cuando anteriormente logre hacer correr el pkg para los ejecutables)

Cabe mencionar que ya he buscado mucho acerca de esto pero no he encontrado solución, me da un problema con jsdom.

Nuevamente muchas gracias, espero puedan brincarme su apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la forma de solucionar el problema, solo s debe eliminar la careta jsdom de node_modules, y enseguida funciona todo con normalidad.